# Set Bluetooth audio device to always use AD2P on Linux

Tags: linux, audio, bluetooth, arch-linux, pulse-audio

I have a bluetooth speaker that works perfectly on my Arch Linux, but whenever I connect it's in HSV and I must [manually set the protocol to A2DP](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_headset#Switch_between_HSV_and_A2DP_setting).

How can I make it always use AD2P by default on connect?
Preferable if it works for any bluetooth audio device.

Comment: I did find one a while back which I think used `pacmd  set-default-sink`, which worked temporarily occasionally in the case of some disconnects (may have just memorised the correct command with `bluez_sink.MAC.a2dp_sink` as the option instead of [this script](https://askubuntu.com/a/773391/178596)). [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/186830/52956) requests something similar, so of course has no answers. Alternativly as HSV seems to be the default on Fedora too, could submit a bug report to the devellopers (which ones?) to request this is the default one or is is settable